# COM object creation in C# form

Tags: c#, forms, com

My first C# console program works well, so I am moving now to a program using Forms. I have a label1, lable2  a button1, and I want to create a button2. everything works, but can't figure out how to  use the same COM object in button2 without having to define it again.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dynamic scope = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("LeCroy.XStreamDSO"));
    }

    public void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "reading back instrument ID";
        button1.Text = " 2s pause between successives commands...";
        dynamic scope = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("LeCroy.XStreamDSO"));
        dynamic Replay = scope.InstrumentID;
        var Replayvalue = Replay.Value;
        var Replaytype = Replay.type;
        label1.Text = "You are connected to scope model:" + Replayvalue;
        label2.Text = "Going to recall default setup";
        dynamic CMD = scope.SaveRecall.Setup.DoRecallDefaultPanel.ActNow();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text = "  all  Done!";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        label2.Text += "\nTrigger mode Auto";
        CMD = scope.Acquisition.TriggerMode = "Auto";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text += "\nShow measurements ";
        CMD = scope.Measure.ShowMeasure = true; // turn measure panel on
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text += "\nHorizontal scale up";
        CMD = scope.Acquisition.Horizontal.HorScaleUp.ActNow;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text += "\nHorizontal scale up one more time..";
        CMD = scope.Acquisition.Horizontal.HorScaleUp.ActNow;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text += "\nShow measurements statistics";
        scope.Measure.StatsOn = true;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text += "\nTrigger mode Single";
        scope.Acquisition.TriggerMode = "Single";  //set single trigger mode 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text += "\nclear all sweeps";
        CMD = scope.Measure.ClearSweeps;  //clear sweeps in messurements
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text += "\nTrigger mode Single...again";
        scope.Acquisition.TriggerMode = "Single";  //set single trigger mode 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text = "\nall commands executed!";

        button1.Text = "click here to redo all...";

    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic CMD = scope.SaveRecall.Setup.DoRecallDefaultPanel.ActNow();
    }
}
```

}

I get the error "the name  **scope** doen't exist" in button2_click. CMD was defined in button1_click, so doesn't exist in button2_click and I can understand this, but why doesn't scope exist when defined in Form1_load and/or even in main? I do not know how to declare it and make it visible in all fucntions in Form1 without having to release and redefine it in each action button. Is there a way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can move it to a higher scope, ie right under your class declaration and leave it empty (null) then you can acess it with button2 but it will always be null until u assign it with button one first.

Comment: I am no so sure I have understood what to do but will try... WIll let you knowhow it goes. Thanks